# Passing to a method a inheriting-component as a parameter using its base-class

Tags: angular, oop, inheritance

(I am building a modal-system that accepts inheriting components and shows them)

I am trying to pass an inheriting-component to a method using its base-class as type.

```typescript
@Component(...) export class BaseCompComponent implements OnInit

@Component(...) export class ActualComponent extends BaseCompComponent {
```

```typescript
  method(b:BaseCompComponent) { }

  Calling it like so: method(ActualComponent) --> ERROR
```

ERROR:

Argument of type 'typeof ActualComponent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BaseCompComponent'.
  Property 'ngOnInit' is missing in type 'typeof ActualComponent' but required in type 'BaseCompComponent'.

The base-class implements this, what am I doing wrong? This seems fairly straightforward OOP ?

(If the question isn't clear I also wrote a sample on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x8tnty)

See 'Hello' component Line #19)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify that `ActualComponent` is type not object.

```js
import { Component, Input, Type } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseCompComponent } from './base-comp/base-comp.component'
import { ActualComponent } from './actual/actual.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {

  @Input() name: string;

  method(b: Type<BaseCompComponent>) { 

  }
  constructor () { 
    this.method(ActualComponent);
  }
}
```